# Data sent to server using jquery get not requiring strings to be declared in quotations?

Tags: jquery, get

When using Jquery's get function I found a code snippet which I have implemented in which data is sent to the server. the data is given to the get function as a dictionary. In this dictionary the keys act as strings yet are not wrapped in quotations. The values in this dictionary are wrapped as strings. Can anyone explain what the difference is? the variable name and time are NOT defined anywhere previously in the script.
Included is the entire script below.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        $('button').click(function () {
            $.get('query.php',{ name: "John", time: "2pm" },function (data) {
                alert(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an [Object Initialiser](http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.5) or [literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals), the keys aren't strictly evaluated as *Expressions*.

Instead, they're limited to only 3 possible options:

```
PropertyName :
    IdentifierName
    StringLiteral
    NumericLiteral
```

While `StringLiteral`s and `NumberLiteral`s will be evaluated as normal for their values, `IdentifierName`s are evaluated for their names.

So, in your snippet, `name` and `time` are the properties' actual names. Even if similar variables did exists, they wouldn't actually be used:

```
var time = 'foo';

console.log({ time: 'bar' });
// { "time": "bar" } rather than { "foo": "bar" }
```

If you wanted to use a variable as a key, you would actually need to use [bracket member operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation):

```
var o = {};
o[time] = 'bar';

console.log(o);
// { "foo": "bar" }
```

The values, on the other hand, are evaluated as normal Expressions. So, variables and other literals can all be used.

```
console.log({ bar: time, baz: true, qux: [ "Lorem", "ipsum" ] });
// { "bar": "foo", "baz": true, qux: [ "Lorem", "ipsum" ] }
```

Answer (score 3):

The code you're asking about is a JavaScript object literal:

```
{
    name: "John",
    time: "2pm"
}
```

You could write the object literal this way and it would mean exactly the same thing:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "time": "2pm"
}
```

You have another object literal in the preceding line:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

That would mean the same thing it it were written as:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ "cache": false });
```

or:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ 'cache': false });
```

Put another way, the property names in an object literal do not generally require quotes. You only have to quote a property name if the name is not a valid JavaScript identifier, for example if it has spaces in it:

```
{
    "my name": "John",
    "the time": "2pm"
}
```

If you wrote that this way it would be invalid:

```
{
    my name: "John",
    the time: "2pm"
}
```

So here the quotes are required. But in the object literal you used, they are not required, and it means the same thing whether you use them or not.

Note that this is different from some other languages, where a quoted name or unquoted name in a hash or map actually mean different things. In Ruby, an unquoted name in a hash is a variable reference. In JSON, property names must always be quoted. But in a JavaScript object literal, you can leave the quotes out when the name is a valid JavaScript identifier.